# NumPy and SciPy - Difference between .todense() and .toarray()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am wondering if there is any difference (advantage/disadvantage) of using `.toarray()` vs. `.todense()` on sparse NumPy arrays. E.g.,

```py
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
sparse_m = sp.sparse.bsr_matrix(np.array([[1,0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,0,1]]))

%timeit sparse_m.toarray()
1000 loops, best of 3: 299 µs per loop

%timeit sparse_m.todense()
1000 loops, best of 3: 305 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`toarray` returns an ndarray; `todense` returns a matrix. If you want a matrix, use `todense`; otherwise, use `toarray`.

Answer (score 0):

As [its documentation states](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), using `numpy.matrix` is discouraged as it may be removed in the future. So it's probably better to use `toarray()` rather than `todense()`, especially since the matrix operations that were convenient on `matrix` objects are now possible on `ndarray` objects since numpy 1.10.