# Scikit-learn's Pipeline: Error with multilabel classification. A sparse matrix was passed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, text-classification

I am implementing different classifiers using different machine learning algorithms.

I'm sorting text files, and do as follows:

```
classifier = Pipeline([
('vectorizer', CountVectorizer ()),
('TFIDF', TfidfTransformer ()),
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier (GaussianNB()))])
classifier.fit(X_train,Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

When I use the algorithm GaussianNB the following error occurs:

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. 
>   Use X.toarray () to convert to a dense numpy array.

I saw the following post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384680/scikit-learns-pipeline-a-sparse-matrix-was-passed-but-dense-data-is-required)

In this post a class is created to perform the transformation of the data.
It is possible to adapt my code with TfidfTransformer.
How I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
class DenseTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return X.todense()

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X)

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

classifier = Pipeline([
('vectorizer', CountVectorizer ()),
('TFIDF', TfidfTransformer ()),
('to_dense', DenseTransformer()), 
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier (GaussianNB()))])
classifier.fit(X_train,Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Now, as a part of your pipeline, the data will be transform to dense representation.

BTW, I don't know your constraints, but maybe you can use another classifier, such as [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or [SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) that DO accept data in sparse representation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes. I've tried other as SVM algorithm and RandomForest and have accepted a parse representation