# Are all the features correctly selected and used in a classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I would like to know if when I use a classifier, for example:

```
random_forest_bow = Pipeline([
        ('rf_tfidf',Feat_Selection. countV),
        ('rf_clf',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=300,n_jobs=3))
        ])
    
random_forest_ngram.fit(DataPrep.train['Text'],DataPrep.train['Label'])
predicted_rf_ngram = random_forest_ngram.predict(DataPrep.test_news['Text'])
np.mean(predicted_rf_ngram == DataPrep.test_news['Label'])
```

I am also considering other features in the model. I defined X and y as follows:

```
X=df[['Text','is_it_capital?', 'is_it_upper?', 'contains_num?']]
y=df['Label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=40) 

df_train= pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
df_test = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)

countV = CountVectorizer()
train_count = countV.fit_transform(df.train['Text'].values)
```

My dataset looks as follows

```
Text                             is_it_capital?     is_it_upper?      contains_num?   Label
an example of text                      0                  0               0            0
ANOTHER example of text                 1                  1               0            1
What's happening?Let's talk at 5        1                  0               1            1
```

I would like to use as features also `is_it_capital?`,`is_it_upper?`,`contains_num?`, but since they have binary values (1 or 0, after encoding), I should apply BoW only on Text to extract extra features.
Maybe my question is obvious, but since I am a new ML learner and I am not familiar with classifiers and encoding, I will be thankful for all the support and comments that you will provide. Thanks

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly use your "extra" features like `is_it_capital?`, `is_it_upper?`, and `contains_num?`. It seems you're struggling with how exactly to combine the two seemingly disparate feature sets. You could use something like [sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) or [sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) to apply your different encoding strategies to each set of features. There's no reason you couldn't use your extra features in combinations with whatever a text-feature extraction method (e.g. your BoW approach) would produce.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['this is some text', 'this is some MORE text', 'hi hi some text 123', 'bananas oranges'], 'is_it_upper': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'contains_num': [0, 0, 1, 0]})

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

transformer = ColumnTransformer([('text', CountVectorizer(), 'text')], remainder='passthrough')
X = transformer.fit_transform(df)

print(X)
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
print(transformer.get_feature_names())
['text__123', 'text__bananas', 'text__hi', 'text__is', 'text__more', 'text__oranges', 'text__some', 'text__text', 'text__this', 'is_it_upper', 'contains_num']
```

More on your specific example:

```py
X=df[['Text','is_it_capital?', 'is_it_upper?', 'contains_num?']]
y=df['Label']

# Need to use DenseTransformer to properly concatenate results
# from CountVectorizer and other transformer steps
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
class DenseTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return X.todense()

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
     ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()), 
     ('to_dense', DenseTransformer()), 
])

transformer = ColumnTransformer([('text', pipeline, 'Text')], remainder='passthrough')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=40)

X_train = transformer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = transformer.transform(X_test)

df_train = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
df_test = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, black site. Yes, I am struggling with this problem, as it is not fully clear to me how to include those features. From your example, it seems that I should apply ColumnTransformer before splitting into train/test. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. Apply the ColumnTransformer to your training dataset (`df_train`) using the `fit`/`fit_transform` methods. Then, apply the transformer to your test dataset (`df_test`) using *only the `transform`* method, since we've already learned what our training dataset needs to look like from the `fit`/`fit_transform` methods. More on fit/fit_transform [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models).

Comment: Very, very similar to what you've done in your example with the CountVectorizer. The result of the ColumnTransformer process will give you your input matrices for training and test (`X_train`/`X_test`). I updated my answer above.

Comment: thanks for your answer and update on that. I tried to follow what you suggested, but I got the error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid . Any idea on how I can fix it?

Comment: You could do something like what's detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28384887/5015569). Edits above.

Answer (score 2):

What I found useful is to have my transformation in a way that I have total control. For each set of columns, I would perform a specific transformation, and then in the end I union my transformations: Here is example

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# boolean
boolean_features = ['is_it_capital?', 'is_it_upper?','contains_num?',]
boolen_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent',)),
)
    ]
)

text_features = 'Text'
text_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[('vectorizer', CountVectorizer())]
)

# merge all pipelines

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('bool', boolean_transformer, boolean_features),
        ('text', text_transformer, text_features),
    ]
)

pipelines = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('model', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=300,n_jobs=3))
    ]
)

# spilt data to train and test
X_train_, X_test, y_train_, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.1, random_state=42, stratify=y)


# we can train our model
pipelines.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)

# what is awesome is using other tools like GridSearch becomes easy.

params = {'model__ n_estimators': [100, 200, 300], 'model__ criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']}

clf = GridSearchCV(
    pipelines, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, param_grid=params, scoring='roc_auc'
)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict for totally unseen data
clf.predict(X_test)
```

#### Updates

If we have columns that needs no transformation and need to be included, add `remainder='passthrough'`

```py
# assumption: above code does not have boolen_X
# ...
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('text', text_transformer, text_features),

    ], remainder='passthrough'
)
#...
```

See scikit-learn documentations and usage examples:

- [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Prayson. One question: may I apply the transformer for numeral variables even if I already have no NAs values and variables already encoded in 1 and 0 for them?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter if there are no NAs. But if you don’t want any transformation then add `remainder='passthrough'`. I will update my answer